# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception:the column name count(pr) is not valid

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, netbeans

I am using sql server and when i write this sql select statement it runs well when i use it in netbean it show error 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception:the column name count(pr) is not valid
i write code below can any one help me

```
try{ String sql="SELECT count(status) from Sub_Data"; 
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);   
       rs=pst.executeQuery();   
        if(rs.next()){ 
        String count4=rs.getString("count(status)");
        totall111.setText(count4);
        }
       catch(Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e );  
        }
```

Comment: Did you Debug your program. I think your program throw exception from another part of code. Check your code maybe you use an 'AS' clause in the statement and retrieve the column value by actual column name

Answer (score 3):

either change it to

```
SELECT count(status) as c from Sub_Data
...
rs.getInt ("c");
```

or just use the columnIndex

```
rs.getInt (1);
```

**Edit**

`count` would return an Int not a String

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
try{ String sql="SELECT count(status) from Sub_Data"; 
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);   
       rs=pst.executeQuery();   
        if(rs.next()){ 
        String count4=rs.getString(1);
            totall111=Integer.valueOf(count4);


        }
       catch(Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e );


    }
```